# What are the possible failure reasons for addobserver class method in iOS8

Tags: ios8, apple-push-notifications

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(policyChanged:) name:@"notification" object:nil];
```

above is the code, I am using for addobserver. and my app was crashing with the below error

assertion failed: 12B411: libxpc.dylib + 51947 [DBA1E85F-5C4C-3026-9B98-A82D2E332ED6]: 0x7d

But its working fine in iOS7